# Why does the background affect the border-radius in this keyframe animation?

Tags: css, animation, keyframe

In this keyframe animation, everything that I want to animate works, but when you remove the background colour change from the animation, it breaks the border-radius animation. I know the border-radius is actually applying but because we're using scale instead of changing the actual height and width of the div it's not visible. But what I don't understand is why adding in the background change to the animation changes this and allows the border-radius animation to do what you expect it to do.

```
<div class="square"></div>

.square {
    width: 350px;
    height: 350px;
    margin: 200px auto;
    background: #41A9F0;
    animation: box 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes box {
    0% {
      transform: scale(0.2) rotate(0deg);
      border-radius: 0;
    }
    50% {
     transform: scale(2) rotate(180deg);
     border-radius: 50%;
     background:#5ABE8A;
    }
    100% {
      transform: scale(0.2) rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

Comment: you can specify what properties to transform

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but when I run your code and remove the background color you have your animation, I see no difference. Do you have a fiddle or example of the issue?

Comment: here's a fiddle with the background colour commented out.
https://jsfiddle.net/b42z596L/4/ @bgaynor78

Comment: I still don't see the issue. Here they are in a fiddle side by side. To my eye, they look the same [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/brettgaynor/omdgf96e/11/)

Comment: turns out it's a browser issue, but I still don't understand it. I'm in firefox